# auto increment field in Peewee

Tags: peewee

Is there a way to define autoincrement Field in peewee.

I understand we could define sequence but the need to create the sequence manually and not managed by create_tables deters me from using it. ( The build process is managed by create tables and I would prefer not to add manual steps )

```
import peewee
class TestModel(peewee.Model):
    test_id = peewee.BigIntegerField(sequence='test_id_seq')
```

Alternate to the above code I would rather have. As most databases have serial field I dont see a point maintaining a sequence.

```
import peewee
class TestModel(peewee.Model):
    test_id = peewee.AutoIncremenetIntField()
```

Comment: Peewee automatically adds an autoincrementing "id" field if another primary key isn't specified. Is there a reason that this doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either you can use `PrimaryKeyField()` as @wyatt mentioned in comment

or you can use [Playhouse- Signal Support (peewee extensions)](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html?highlight=auto_increment#signal-support)

```
from playhouse.signals import Model, pre_save

class MyModel(Model):
    data = IntegerField()

@pre_save(sender=MyModel)
def on_save_handler(model_class, instance, created):
    # find max value of temp_id in model
    # increment it by one and assign it to model instance object
    next_value = MyModel.select(fn.Max(MyModel.temp_id))[0].temp_id +1
    instance.temp_id = next_value
```

Comment: there is a typo (you imported post_save method but you used pre_save)

Comment: Thanks @Pisti, fixed that, it should be pre_save signal

Answer (score 7):

The given answers here are outdated but this was still my first Google search result.

Peewee has a special field type for an auto incrementing primary key called **AutoField**:

> The AutoField is used to identify an auto-incrementing integer primary
>   key. If you do not specify a primary key, Peewee will automatically
>   create an auto-incrementing primary key named “id”.

Take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html#primary-keys-composite-keys-and-other-tricks). Example usage:

```
class Event(Model):
  event_id = AutoField()  # Event.event_id will be auto-incrementing PK.
```

Comment: Note this [caveat from the Peewee AutoField docs](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#AutoField) when dealing with SQLite. 
"In conjunction with SQLite having foreign keys disabled by default (meaning ON DELETE is ignored, even if you specify it explicitly), this can lead to surprising and dangerous behaviour. To avoid this, you may want to use one or both of AutoIncrementField and pragmas=[('foreign_keys', 'on')] when you instantiate SqliteDatabase."